# dynamic filter in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a data set sales and another data set promotion.
promotion data set has details of when the sales promotion has occurred. Now, I need to identify the data from sales that are associated to a particular promotion.

I have extracted the first row and created a filter

```
promo.filter="product.no==1100001369 & (customer.state==TN | customer.state==AP) & (cgrp==12 | cgrp==13)"
```

tried

```
promo.sales<-filter(sales, promo.filter)
```

and I get the following error

```
Error: filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector.
```

How to I get this done.

Comment: that is `filter` from `dplyr`?

Comment: try `quote(your Filter)`, ie `quote(product.no==1100001369 & (customer.state==TN | customer.state==AP) ...)`

Comment: Try `filter_(sales, promo.filter)`

Comment: yes, used filter from dplyr

Comment: Thank you, filter_(sales, promo.filter) worked for me.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré can you post that as an answer so that drv can accept it as the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `filter_(sales, promo.filter)`

---

From the [non-standard evaluation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html) vignette:

> Every function in dplyr that uses NSE also has a version that uses SE.
>   There’s a consistent naming scheme: the SE is the NSE name with `_` on
>   the end. For example, the SE version of `summarise()` is `summarise_()`,
>   the SE version of `arrange()` is `arrange_()`. These functions work very
>   similarly to their NSE cousins, but the inputs must be “quoted”